# Get S3 file size of uploaded file

Tags: php, fine-uploader

My developer who installed FineUploader said he could send the file size of an uploaded S3 file in an email. His code returned file size=o always and he can not solve it. I was just wondering if it is even possible.
   var file_size = 0; is in the fineuploader javascript embed
$file_size = $_REQUEST['filesize']; is in the s3handler.php email portion he created

Comment: We would need a lot more detail to be able to help. But it is immaterial as you say that you are not a developer yourself, and we won't do it for you - we will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the size of the file in S3 server side via S3's API  (look at the [HEAD object request](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html)).  The most appropriate time to do this may be when Fine Uploader sends an [upload success request](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/endpoint_handlers/amazon-s3.html#optional-server-side-tasks-all-browsers) to your server.

I would suggest you encourage your developer to get his/her own stack exchange account.  Filtering questions through you is probably not the most efficient workflow.